# What are SYS_BOOT registers in beagle bone black ? What is the significance of SYS_BOOT[4:0] , SYS_BOOT[15:0] , SYS_BOOT[15:14] registers?

Tags: beagleboneblack

I have a little idea about these registers, they get values at on or reset from sys_pin voltage during boot time, the values varies when S2 key is pressed or released state. I have two questions basically.

1. **How values are stored** (does it maintain an array like SYS_BOOT[15:0] SYS_BOOT[15:1]SYS_BOOT[15:2] ....)
2. The system also reads value stored in SYS_BOOT[4:0] and depending upon that it create boot device list. Now **what is the boot device list** ??

Please help me out with clear and simple explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Boot ROM memory on AM335x chip of Beaglebone contains a small bootloader code, hereby referred to as ROM code. Upon power-up or reset, this ROM code starts execution and checks the state of the 16 SYSBOOT pins [0:15]. These pins are actually LCD_DATA0 - LCD_DATA15 pins in the processor's datasheet. The first 5 SYSBOOT pins determine the order of the boot devices (which device to boot from first) while the rest of the pins have their own meaning. For complete details, see Table 26-7 in the AM335x TRM https://mythopoeic.org/BBB-PRU/am335x_techref.pdf. Below, you can see the Boot Sequence (list of boot devices) for each combination of the first 5 SYSBOOT pins (SYSBOOT[4:0]).
[image] 
As these pins are also being used for interfacing LCD, they function as SYSBOOT pins only during the execution of ROM code and are usually pulled-up/down and some of them can be set/reset using switches/buttons (that's how the push button on the Beaglebone Black works to boot from external SD card instead of internal eMMC).
The ROM code maintains a list of available boot devices (configurable by first 5 SYSBOOT pins) and tries to boot from the first device from the list. If the boot fails, it tries the next and so on. Here's the boot sequence of ROM code.
[image]

Comment: @UdhayDevgotra I am glad it helped. I would appreciate it if you could accept my answer or mark it as useful. Thanks